# How to auto look up for the start point of largest break in a given dataset in R

Tags: r

I am trying to find the starting point of the largest break of a given data. Here is my example:

```
data <- data.frame(month = c(1:12), countx = c(60,69,10,13,65,80,59,84,43,21,18,10))
select <- data[data$countx >= 50,]            #take value greater than 50 into account    

# find the break
wtym <- select$month
breaks <-  c(0, which(diff(wtym) != 1), length(wtym))
allbreak <- sapply(seq(length(breaks) - 1 ),
        function(i) wtym[(breaks[i] + 1):breaks[i+1]])
> allbreak
[[1]]
[1] 1 2
[[2]]
[1] 5 6 7 8
```

The question is: I need to find this for a large number of dataset (and the breaks are obviously varied), is there any way to auto pick up the start point of the largest break in a series (in this example, it is number 5 (gap no.2)? Any idea is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is `wtym`?

Comment: Sorry, I edit a bit from my original code, thus, one line is missing. It was edit above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a run-length-encoding `?rle` task where you are looking for runs of `x < 50` and `x >= 50`. Here's a function:

```
bigbreak <- function(x, cutoff) {
  r <- rle(x >= cutoff)
  cumsum(r$l)[which(r$l == max(r$l[r$v]) & r$v)-1]+1
}

bigbreak(data$countx, 50)
#[1] 5
```

Now let's try it on 5 million records:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(c(50,0), 5e6, replace=TRUE)
system.time({
  bigbreak(x, 50)
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.41    0.00    0.41
```

Under half a second, not too bad.

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you so much. 
I actually run for large number of dataset (about 1000 single files) but each result from a file has the two-column dataframe (as example). So, if one file is solved, I can put them into a loop to perform all. Thanks a gain.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `dplyr` and `data.table`.

```
# Create example data frame
data <- data.frame(month = c(1:12), countx = c(60,69,10,13,65,80,59,84,43,21,18,10))

# Load package
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

# Process the data
data2 <- data %>%
  mutate(Condition = countx >= 50) %>%
  mutate(RunID = rleid(Condition)) %>%
  filter(Condition) %>%
  group_by(RunID) %>%
  mutate(num = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(num == max(num))

# Show the number of the first month
data2$month[1]
[1] 5
```

Comment: That's great. Seems like what I need. But when I run, I got message "Error in max(n) : invalid 'type' (closure) of argument". Don't you have same message?

Comment: Please see my update. It is possible that R get confused because of the column name `n` and the function `n()` are similar. I change the column name from `n` to `num`. Try again to see if it helps.